# A linear transformation $f$ that maps the circle $|z+1|=2$ onto the circle $|w+i|=3$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a linear transformation $f$ that maps the circle $|z+1|=2$ onto the circle $|w+i|=3$.

My guess is $w=f(z)=\frac{3}{2}iz$, since we're trying to find a function that maps a circle centered at $(-1,0)$ with radius $2$ to a circle centered at $(0,-1)$ with radius $3$. So multiplying by $i$ rotates the center $\pi/2$ counterclockwise and multiplying by $3/2$ magnifies the radius to $3$.

However, I can't show that $|f(z)+i|=3$. I get $|f(z)+i|=|i||\frac{3}{2}z+1|=|\frac{3}{2}z+1|$, so I can't show that this value is $3$. I'd appreciate some help to this problem.

Comment: Your $f$ does not work for $f(-1)=-3\frac{i}{2}\neq -i$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Try $w=f(z)=az+b$. You are on the right way concerning the scaling factor!

Answer (score 1):

A simple idea : first translate the points to a circle of center 0 and radius 2, then scale the circle to 3, then translate the points to a circle of center $-i$

The first translation is $z \mapsto z+1$
The second translation is $z \mapsto \frac{3}{2}z$
The last translation is $z \mapsto z-i$

And this gives you

$z\mapsto  \frac{3}{2}(z+1)-i$

Comment: I see so the important part was to magnify the circle after moving it to the center since otherwise the center point is scaled as well. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

(See my comment above) however your intuition is right we need to map the center of the circle to the center of the image circle and have a dilation of the radius by $\frac{3}{2}$ so the solution should be such that
$$f(z)+i=\frac{3}{2}e^{i\theta}(z+1)$$
Where $\theta$ is an arbitrary angle